# Stokes' Theorem problem (right triangle)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to demonstrate the truth of Stokes' Theorem ($\int_T curl(\vec{v}) \cdot \vec{da} = \int_{\partial T} \vec{v} \cdot \vec{dl}$) in the following problem/case:

Let $\vec{v} = x y \hat{x} + 2y z \hat{y} + 3x z \hat{z} = (x y, 2y z, 3x z)$ and $T$ be the right triangle with vertices $O=(0,0,0), A=(0,2,0), B=(0,0,2)$. The boundary $\partial T$ is oriented counterclockwise. Partition $\partial T$ into paths with $P_1 = \overline{OA}, P_2 = \overline{AB}, P_3 = \overline{BO}$ with those orientations. Let $\vec{da}$ denote the vector perpendicular to $T$, determined by the right-hand rule applied to $\partial T$, and with magnitude equal to the area enclosed by an infinitesimal patch of area within $T$. Let $\vec{dl} = (dx, dy, dz)$.

---

My work follows:

First, we know that $x=0$ throughout the problem because $T$ is in the plane $span(\hat{y}, \hat{z})$. By the orientation of the paths, $\hat{da} = \hat{x}$. Following the formula for the area of a triangle, we then have $\vec{da}= \frac{1}{2} \hat{x}dy dz$.

Left hand side: $curl(\vec{v}) = (-2y, -3z, -x)$. Therefore, $\int_T curl(\vec{v}) \cdot \vec{da} = \int_T (-2y, -3z, -x) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \hat{x}dy dz = \int (-2y(1/2))dydz = -2*2 = -4$.

Right hand side: Consider each path in turn, and then sum the results. On $P_1$, $z=0$; therefore, $\vec{v} = (0, 0, 0)$ and thus $\int_{P_1} \vec{v} \cdot \vec{dl} = 0$. Likewise, on $P_3$, $y=0$, yielding $\int_{P_3} \vec{v} \cdot \vec{dl} = 0$. That leaves $P_2$. On this path, $z=2-y$; thus $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{dl} = 2y(2-y)dy$; $\int_{P_2} \vec{v} \cdot \vec{dl} = \int_{2}^{0} (4y-2y^2)dy=-\frac{8}{3}$. The total integral is the sum of these parts, so $\int_{\partial T} \vec{v} \cdot \vec{dl} = \sum_{i=1}^3{(\int_{P_i} \vec{v} \cdot \vec{dl})} = -\frac{8}{3}$

---

Obviously, I did something wrong, if the right-hand side is to equal the left-hand side, but where did I err?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your double integral should be:

$$ \int_T (-2y,-3z,-x) \cdot( 1,0,0) \, \mathrm{d}S =  \int^{2}_0  \! \!\!  \int^{2-y}_0 (-2y) \, \mathrm{d}z \,\mathrm{d}y = \int^2_0 (-2y)(2-y) \,  \mathrm{d} y = -8/3.$$

Cheers!

Comment: It has been a month, but I just wanted to thank you. I was quite embarrassed when I realized my mistake. I would like to say that I was just tired, and I will stick to that story! Thanks again for helping me!

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm just glad I helped. Cheers!